# Error: Each initial covariance matrix must be symmetric and positive semidefinite.?

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, classification, gaussian

I am trying to fix, a guassian mixture model to the data using the command.

```
obj = gmdistribution.fit(data,maxk,'Start',S,'CovType','diagonal','Options',opts, 'Regularize', 0.01);
```

I know the error is because the diagonal values in the covariance matrix are zero, But I use a regularize option to avoid it, but it still gives me that error. Is there any other way around this error?

Comment: Can you provide more details of the options you're passing in? Are there negative values in your covariance matrices?

Comment: Hi Issac, the covariance matrix is a diagonal matrix, all non-diagonal are zero, in the options i juts specify the max iterations nothing else. S is a structure with the three fields mu(means), sigma(covariance) and PComponents in the format that is needed.

Comment: When you say the covariance matrix is a diagonal, you know that you need to only specify the diagonal itself (as a vector, not a matrix) when using the 'diagonal' option?

Comment: Yes, I specify only the diagonal elements.

Comment: Without more details it's hard to say anything useful. Can you put together a [simple, self-contained script that reproduces your error](http://www.sscce.org/)?